# Watching Netflix in Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 generates error F7355

Tags: firefox, netflix, drm

I've just set up a laptop with brand new Ubuntu 20.04 and visited Netflix in Firefox.

There was a yellow toaster underneath the address bar stating

> You must enable DRM to play some audio or video on this page

So I clicked 'Enable DRM'. Then I saw "Firefox is installing components... please try again later" and after that went away I reloaded Netflix but it still would not play. When I play back video I get Netflix error F7355.

[image]

Then it points me to https://help.netflix.com where I can only find information on this error when I have trouble playing back on macOS or Windows. But I don't use those, I use Linux...

I understand that I can probably install Chrome which will *Just Work* - but I don't use Chrome. It seems like it *could* work but I'm missing something. What should I do to watch Netflix in Firefox on Linux on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Make sure to follow *all* the steps in my answer and let me know if it works...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this definitely helped. So after the above steps that I got (the DRM popup in Firefox) the DRM settings in the browser were already there and the add-ons installed. After I installed libavcodec-extra I was now also able to play back content! I wonder though, I already chose non-free install in the installation process to make sure my wifi worked. It would have been great if Ubuntu then also installed libavcodec-extra. Watching Netflix is not really an obscure use case.

Comment: I agree.. Glad to help..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have DRM enabled and thus you are missing Widevine plugin to decode the DRM protected Netflix content.

1. First make sure you have the media codecs installed

   ```
   sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
   ```
2. Then enable DRM:

   Open Firefox and type `about:preferences#content` in the address bar. Look for Digital Rights Management (DRM) Content field and check the box in front of Play DRM-controlled content.

   [image: enabling DRM on firefox]

   This will start to install the Widevine plugin from Google. Depending on your network speed it will take a few minutes to install this add-on.
3. Make sure that you have the required add-ons:

   Open a new tab in Firefox and type `about:addons` in the address bar. Make sure that you have Widevine and OpenH264 add-ons installed with ‘Always Active’ mode.

   [image: screenshot]
4. Restart Firefox.

You should know be able to play Netflix via the Firefox web browser.

Comment: I would not have spend such a good evening without your answer! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to activate DRM on firefox and install the following package:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra ffmpeg
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying  full afternoon the above and more without result,  the following worked for me:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt full-upgrade

sudo apt install libwidevinecdm0
```

I found this here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/03/raspberry-pi-os-gets-official-widevine.html