# Netflix Error Code F7355

Tags: video-streaming, minimal-install

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fosa) **minimal installation** on my machine.
I can't stream Netflix videos. It returns **Error Code F7355**.
Same problem happens with Firefox and Chromium.
DRM is activated by default.
I did not have this problem with previous **full/normal installations** of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THE ISSUE**

Ubuntu's **minimal installation** (20.04 and previous versions) doesn't come with one or some codecs required for streaming Netflix. It's not an issue with the web browser (Firefox, Chromium, etc), nor with DRM, since it comes activated by default these days.

The error message informed by Netflix doesn't help to understand nor to solve the issue (image below copied from https://help.netflix.com/en/node/105186).

---

[image: Netflix Error Message Page]

---

**THE SOLUTION**

- Close Firefox.
- Open the terminal and install `FFMPEG`:

```
   sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

- Close the terminal.
- Re-open Firefox.
- Done!

**NOTES**

- [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It's known as the "Swiss-army-knife in the field"!
- I am just not sure exactly witch of it's dependency libraries solves the problem.
  At [Ask Ubuntu Question 1237114](https://askubuntu.com/q/1237114/254056) the solution is attributed to `libavcodec-extra`.
  Actually, I think `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56`, witch is a dependency of both `ffmpeg` and `libavcodec-extra`, is where relies the solution. Didn't try it alone though.

Comment: Doesn't work as of Oct 8, 2020 on a fresh install of Ubuntu and firefox. Unable to stream from any paid site, but youtube works before and after trying to this tut...

Comment: @jamie Is DRM enabled on your Firefox installation?