# Can't read Netflix nor Prime videos

Tags: firefox, netflix, drm, libav

I am new to Linux and I'm trying Ubuntu 20.04.1 on a USB key to see what it's like.
I wanted to watch a movie on Prime Video using Firefox, but I couldn't : it asked me to allow DRM, which I did.
But still, I wasn't able to watch my movie (says an error occured) and I tried on Netflix (error F7355): issue is the same.

I have been looking on the internet for a solution but I couldn't find any. I have :

- Updated Firefox using `sudo apt install --only-upgrade firefox`
- Changed `media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete;false` to `true` in Firefox `about:config`
- Checked that I have OpenH264 and Widevine plugins activated
- Tried commands I found online... Such as `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra`, `sudo apt-get update && apt-cache search libavcodec-extra`, `sudo apt-cache search libav | grep extra-` or `sudo apt-cache search libav | grep extra-`...

Most of the posts I found were pretty old. It seems like i'm missing this "libavcodec" but I don't really know what it is nor how I should get it.

I can play YouTube videos, however Twitch videos do not work (Error 4000)

Could anyone help me ? I was happy with my Linux experience so far, but I'm a bit disapointed that it's so hard to do something as simple as watching a stream !

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Have you opened Firefox, clicked on Preferences, scrolled down and enabled DRM content?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to mention it but it's been done. BTW here's one one the thread I followed : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237114/watching-netflix-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-20-04-generates-error-f7355?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watching Netflix in Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 generates error F7355](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237114/watching-netflix-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-20-04-generates-error-f7355). Also: [12.04 - Netflix error code F7355-1204 and F7363-1260 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/906822/349837)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu (was using a USB version) and the command `sudo apt install libavcodec-extra` worked.
After enabling DRM in Firefox and rebooting the app, I'm now able to watch streams.

thanks for your help